# Merge [race] into [racing]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We don't need both [racing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racing) and [race](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possible split here between

- [race] watching a race, questions about someone else's approach
- [racing] competing in a race, strategy/tactics or fueling etc.

However on looking closer, there's 47 questions in [race] and 168 in [racing] and based on title there's a blend of both in either tag and likely some dupes too.

IMO they're close enough for synonomising.

---

```
race will be removed from 47 posts
racing will be added to 43 posts
```

Done

Comment: If you would rather give them different scopes and sort questions, I'm fine with that, too.

Comment: @Michael That sounds like work.

Comment: @DavidW concur - and it will clutter the home page with edits.   I suggest combining the two, with [race] as the root and racing as the synonom.